# Entity field form Symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony

My goal is to display a social networks form in users dashboard like :

```
 - Facebook : <input>
 - Twitter : <input>
 - Linkedin : <input>
```

Social networks are dynamic (manage by administration panel).
I've got currently 3 Entities (Social, UserSocial and User (FOS...)).
In User entity, I just added it :

```
 /**
     *@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Application\SocialBundle\Entity\UserSocial", mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $userSocials;
```

My Social entity :

```
class Social
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $class;

    ...
}
```

My UserSocial entity :

```
class UserSocial
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     *@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Admin\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="userSocials")
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     *@ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Admin\SocialBundle\Entity\Social", inversedBy="userSocials")
     */
    private $social;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="value", type="string", length=255)
     */
     // Not really sure about it
    private $value;
     ....
```

And finally, the UserSocialType, this is where i'm stuck :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('social', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'Admin\SocialBundle\Entity\Social',
        'property' => 'name',
        'required' => false,
        ))
        ->add('value')
    ;
}
```

It gave me just a select with all social name in DB and a value input. I would like a value input for each social entity in DB.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

May be you do it a little different? 
Craete a SocialType:

```
$builder
        ->add('social', 'text', array(
            'data' => $existingSocial
        ))
        ...
    ;
```

UserSocialType:

```
$builder
    ->add('social', new SocialType(), array(
        // pass social to the Social type
        ...
    ))
    ...
;
```

PS// These are just my general thoughts, here are some wrong lines my snippet, you should not pass an object to the text field, but you can use data transformers to get an object from the text value.. Also I think your UserSocial entity unproperly configured, `$social` field should receive manyToOne relationship